# opencv static cv::CascadeClassifier not work in release mode

Tags: android, c++, opencv

- In android debug mode it can load the model file

```
cv::CascadeClassifier cascade;
assert(cascade.load(opencvModelPath));
```

- Force quit the program without any error message in android release mode

```
string decoded_string = base64_decode(base64Data);
vector<uchar> data(decoded_string.begin(), decoded_string.end());
Mat img = imdecode(data, IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
cv::Mat gray;
std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
equalizeHist(gray, gray);
opencvfaceDetector.detectMultiScale(gray,faces);
```

Comment: verify existence of file at given path. `std::filesystem::exists(opencvModelPath);` verify that contents of the file are actually sensible (not a HTML page or anything). -- if the program exits without messages, _make_ it emit a message after every line of code. insert some printlines.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, the problem is solved, the reason is that the assert assertion does not work in release mode

Comment: what assertion? and how would that make debug mode work but release mode fail?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved.

- the reason is that the assert assertion does not work in release mode